# Apply multisampling/anti-aliasing for specific draw calls, not all of them

Tags: 3d, directx, direct3d, antialiasing

I am aware I can apply multi sampling by setting the sample count on for example 4 and setup the rasterizer stage to apply multi sampling on it. This works great, but right now I want to only apply multi sampling to only a subset of the draw calls I am making. How can I do this?

In psuedo code, this is what I want to achieve:

```
> build vertices data for a simple triangle
> map and copy vertices data to device
> send draw call to device which does NOT apply anti aliasing

> build vertices data for a simple rectangle
> map and copy vertices data to device
> send draw call to device which applies multisampling/antialiasing
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a rasterizer state in Direct3D 11 called `D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC.MultisampleEnable`. It's worth noting, however, that this *only* disables multisample rendering on Direct3D Feature Level 9.x and 10.0. On Direct3D Feature Level 10.1 or later hardware, it doesn't do anything to change how points or triangles are rendered to render targets with a sample count greater than 1. Instead, it sets the line algorithm in combination with `AntialiasedLineEnable` which you can read about on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198.aspx).

In other words, if you are rendering to an MSAA surface, in most cases it's going to be multisampled. **The question is: What are you really trying to accomplish here?**

Comment: I am making some overlay software on top of 3d targets. But since their device is already initialized and some only have a sample count of 1 defined, i need a way to tell the graphics device to apply for example 4x multi sampling to only my draw calls. Without affecting the target 3d program.

Answer (score 1):

As Chuck Walbourn explained, it's not possible to mix single- and multi-sampled rendering to the same render target. However, it's possible to render your multi-sampled content to a texture and resolve that to a single-sampled one. You can render this texture onto your single-sampled render target.

The method for resolving a multi-sampled resource to a single-sampled one is [`ID3D11DeviceContext::ResolveSubresource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476474(v=vs.85).aspx).